# HTC Magic with OpenEclair: Factory reset doesn't work!

Tags: 2.1-eclair, factory-reset, htc-magic

today I got an old HTC Magic phone with OpenEclair (Android 2.1-update) installed on it. Unfortunately there is still the Gmail account of another person linked with it, which I'd like to remove. However, for doing so, you need to do a "factory reset" on the phone. So did I, the phone rebooted, but the data (apps, settings and the account) was still there. Nothing had been removed!

Anyone has an idea what could be the problem and how to fix that?

Thx a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't do a factory reset then, but probably a soft reset. To perform a factory reset from the Home screen press Menu > Settings > SD card & phone storage > Factory data reset > Reset phone > Erase everything. That should take you back to square one. Reply back with a comment if not.

Update:
Boot into the bootloader: Completely power off the deivce. Then hold down the Back button and press the Power/End Call button to restart your phone. Keep the back button held down till the bootloader menu appears. From here do you have an option to wipe, reset, or factory reset (or something along those lines)? If so try it.

Comment: ehm... "SD card & phone storage" doesn't contain a "Factory data reset". What I did is "Menu > Settings > Privacy > Factory data reset > Reset phone > Erase everything". That didn't work however

Comment: Huh, I pulled that from HTC's website. And if you search there are plenty of other sites that state the same method for factory reset. Try the following update in my answer above...

Comment: Yes, I've seen the wrong path on many websites as well...Just did a reflash :) I was lucky and the OpenEclair update zip was still on the SD card. So that works for sure. (+1 for your help)

Comment: So you are running a custom ROM? Wiping Data, cache, and Dalvik cache before doing a reflash usually fixes most problems. If you have any future questions it helps to post that the phone is rooted. I probably would of suggest to just reflash.